# Javascript error in mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am customizing the styles for mobile device support in all my app pages. Right now I have lot of js and css includes in the layout page, I have copied them as is for the mobile layout page.
I am getting this javascript error in the mobile device simulator browser

```
"Result of expresssion aa.AttachEvent[undefined] is not a function"
```

Right now the main layout page contains all css and js as they are there for the main app (jquery 1.7, jquery-ui.min.js and some othe jquery related files )

How do I debug this error in mobile browser?

Comment: don't use the device simulator browser you are using. just set the user agent to a mobile device (you can get a plugin for whatever browser you are using to change the user agent). then use your regular browser debugging tools.

Comment: Ben's spot on. If you're using firefox grab the user-agent-switcher then grab the monster agents file from here : http://techpatterns.com/downloads/firefox/useragentswitcher.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried using firebug?

It will show you the errors and what line of code and the page it is on.

http://getfirebug.com/

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench